DaggerAppComponent not creating in the version
Updated the dagger from the version 2.17 to 2.51.1. both the version not creating the DaggerAppComponent
error: cannot find symbol
import com.app.appscreens.auth.signup.DaggerSignupComponent;

Version:
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$rootProject.daggerVersion"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.daggerVersion"
                                                                 
    ext {
     daggerVersion = '2.51.1'
    }

My Code
@Module
public class SignupModule {

    private AppCompatActivity mActivity;
    public SignupModule(AppCompatActivity activity) {
        this.mActivity = activity;
    }

    @Provides
    AppCompatActivity providesActivity() {
        return mActivity;
    }


    @Provides
    @CustomScopes.AuthScope
    SignupContract.Presenter providesPresenter(SignupPresenter presenter) {
        return presenter;
    }

    @Provides
    @CustomScopes.AuthScope
    CompositeDisposable providesCompositeDisposable() {
        return new CompositeDisposable();
    }
}

In activity:
private SignupComponent mComponent;


     mComponent = DaggerSignupComponent.builder()
              .workoutAppComponent(((WorkoutApplication) getApplicationContext()).getWorkoutAppComponent())
             .signupModule(new SignupModule(this))
             .build();

 public SignupComponent getComponent() {
     return mComponent;
 }


Dagger's inability to generate DaggerSignupComponent means there's probably either a annotation processor error we'll need to see or your Gradle configuration isn't applying as intended. You might have passed this error already, but if Dagger emits an error at the annotation processing stage, please edit your question to include it.
